# MDC context map returning null after migrated to spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, java-17, mdc

I'm depending on MDC context map to fetch the traceId and spanId, but after migrating to spring boot 3.0 MDC context map not returning any of the context variables.

spring boot 3.0 is using logback version as 1.4.6, And I'm also using java17. Do I need to do anything extra to generate the MDC context variables?

Answer (score 1):

Tracing library is moved from sleuth to **io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave**. pls refer the [link](https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3)